# Regex + vee-validate

Tags: regex, vue.js

I use vue.js and vee-validity. I need help with regex.

**Firstname and lastname**

- First letter big, others small
- Allow only letters and UTF-8 characters such as "č,ř,ž,ý,á,í,é,ě,š"
- Do not allow numbers, spaces or special characters

**Nickname**

- Allow only letters (big, small), numbers and UTF-8 characters (same)
- Max 13 characters

**Template**

```
v-validate="{required: true, regex: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ }"
```

Comment: Do you need all cyrillic characters?

Comment: just punctuation for valid czech names for example: Tomáš, Jiří, Šárka

Comment: Usually, I do replace all accented letters with non-accented `é` => `e` and then use plain regexp to check validity. It tends to be easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your First name you can use:

```
^([A-Z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xDE\u0100\u0102\u0104\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u010E\u0110\u0112\u0114\u0116\u0118\u011A\u011C\u011E\u0120\u0122\u0124\u0126\u0128\u012A\u012C\u012E\u0130\u0132\u0134\u0136\u0139\u013B\u013D\u013F\u0141\u0143\u0145\u0147\u014A\u014C\u014E\u0150\u0152\u0154\u0156\u0158\u015A\u015C\u015E\u0160\u0162\u0164\u0166\u0168\u016A\u016C\u016E\u0170\u0172\u0174\u0176\u0178\u0179\u017B\u017D\u0181\u0182\u0184\u0186\u0187\u0189-\u018B\u018E-\u0191\u0193\u0194\u0196-\u0198\u019C\u019D\u019F\u01A0\u01A2\u01A4\u01A6\u01A7\u01A9\u01AC\u01AE\u01AF\u01B1-\u01B3\u01B5\u01B7\u01B8\u01BC\u01C4\u01C7\u01CA\u01CD\u01CF\u01D1\u01D3\u01D5\u01D7\u01D9\u01DB\u01DE\u01E0\u01E2\u01E4\u01E6\u01E8\u01EA\u01EC\u01EE\u01F1\u01F4\u01F6-\u01F8\u01FA\u01FC\u01FE\u0200\u0202\u0204\u0206\u0208\u020A\u020C\u020E\u0210\u0212\u0214\u0216\u0218\u021A\u021C\u021E\u0220\u0222\u0224\u0226\u0228\u022A\u022C\u022E\u0230\u0232\u023A\u023B\u023D\u023E\u0241\u0243-\u0246\u0248\u024A\u024C\u024E\u0370\u0372\u0376\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E\u038F\u0391-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03AB\u03CF\u03D2-\u03D4\u03D8\u03DA\u03DC\u03DE\u03E0\u03E2\u03E4\u03E6\u03E8\u03EA\u03EC\u03EE\u03F4\u03F7\u03F9\u03FA\u03FD-\u042F\u0460\u0462\u0464\u0466\u0468\u046A\u046C\u046E\u0470\u0472\u0474\u0476\u0478\u047A\u047C\u047E\u0480\u048A\u048C\u048E\u0490\u0492\u0494\u0496\u0498\u049A\u049C\u049E\u04A0\u04A2\u04A4\u04A6\u04A8\u04AA\u04AC\u04AE\u04B0\u04B2\u04B4\u04B6\u04B8\u04BA\u04BC\u04BE\u04C0\u04C1\u04C3\u04C5\u04C7\u04C9\u04CB\u04CD\u04D0\u04D2\u04D4\u04D6\u04D8\u04DA\u04DC\u04DE\u04E0\u04E2\u04E4\u04E6\u04E8\u04EA\u04EC\u04EE\u04F0\u04F2\u04F4\u04F6\u04F8\u04FA\u04FC\u04FE\u0500\u0502\u0504\u0506\u0508\u050A\u050C\u050E\u0510\u0512\u0514\u0516\u0518\u051A\u051C\u051E\u0520\u0522\u0524\u0526\u0528\u052A\u052C\u052E\u0531-\u0556\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u13A0-\u13F5\u1E00\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u1E08\u1E0A\u1E0C\u1E0E\u1E10\u1E12\u1E14\u1E16\u1E18\u1E1A\u1E1C\u1E1E\u1E20\u1E22\u1E24\u1E26\u1E28\u1E2A\u1E2C\u1E2E\u1E30\u1E32\u1E34\u1E36\u1E38\u1E3A\u1E3C\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u1E44\u1E46\u1E48\u1E4A\u1E4C\u1E4E\u1E50\u1E52\u1E54\u1E56\u1E58\u1E5A\u1E5C\u1E5E\u1E60\u1E62\u1E64\u1E66\u1E68\u1E6A\u1E6C\u1E6E\u1E70\u1E72\u1E74\u1E76\u1E78\u1E7A\u1E7C\u1E7E\u1E80\u1E82\u1E84\u1E86\u1E88\u1E8A\u1E8C\u1E8E\u1E90\u1E92\u1E94\u1E9E\u1EA0\u1EA2\u1EA4\u1EA6\u1EA8\u1EAA\u1EAC\u1EAE\u1EB0\u1EB2\u1EB4\u1EB6\u1EB8\u1EBA\u1EBC\u1EBE\u1EC0\u1EC2\u1EC4\u1EC6\u1EC8\u1ECA\u1ECC\u1ECE\u1ED0\u1ED2\u1ED4\u1ED6\u1ED8\u1EDA\u1EDC\u1EDE\u1EE0\u1EE2\u1EE4\u1EE6\u1EE8\u1EEA\u1EEC\u1EEE\u1EF0\u1EF2\u1EF4\u1EF6\u1EF8\u1EFA\u1EFC\u1EFE\u1F08-\u1F0F\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F28-\u1F2F\u1F38-\u1F3F\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F\u1F68-\u1F6F\u1FB8-\u1FBB\u1FC8-\u1FCB\u1FD8-\u1FDB\u1FE8-\u1FEC\u1FF8-\u1FFB\u2102\u2107\u210B-\u210D\u2110-\u2112\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u2130-\u2133\u213E\u213F\u2145\u2183\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C60\u2C62-\u2C64\u2C67\u2C69\u2C6B\u2C6D-\u2C70\u2C72\u2C75\u2C7E-\u2C80\u2C82\u2C84\u2C86\u2C88\u2C8A\u2C8C\u2C8E\u2C90\u2C92\u2C94\u2C96\u2C98\u2C9A\u2C9C\u2C9E\u2CA0\u2CA2\u2CA4\u2CA6\u2CA8\u2CAA\u2CAC\u2CAE\u2CB0\u2CB2\u2CB4\u2CB6\u2CB8\u2CBA\u2CBC\u2CBE\u2CC0\u2CC2\u2CC4\u2CC6\u2CC8\u2CCA\u2CCC\u2CCE\u2CD0\u2CD2\u2CD4\u2CD6\u2CD8\u2CDA\u2CDC\u2CDE\u2CE0\u2CE2\u2CEB\u2CED\u2CF2\uA640\uA642\uA644\uA646\uA648\uA64A\uA64C\uA64E\uA650\uA652\uA654\uA656\uA658\uA65A\uA65C\uA65E\uA660\uA662\uA664\uA666\uA668\uA66A\uA66C\uA680\uA682\uA684\uA686\uA688\uA68A\uA68C\uA68E\uA690\uA692\uA694\uA696\uA698\uA69A\uA722\uA724\uA726\uA728\uA72A\uA72C\uA72E\uA732\uA734\uA736\uA738\uA73A\uA73C\uA73E\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA746\uA748\uA74A\uA74C\uA74E\uA750\uA752\uA754\uA756\uA758\uA75A\uA75C\uA75E\uA760\uA762\uA764\uA766\uA768\uA76A\uA76C\uA76E\uA779\uA77B\uA77D\uA77E\uA780\uA782\uA784\uA786\uA78B\uA78D\uA790\uA792\uA796\uA798\uA79A\uA79C\uA79E\uA7A0\uA7A2\uA7A4\uA7A6\uA7A8\uA7AA-\uA7AE\uA7B0-\uA7B4\uA7B6\uFF21-\uFF3A]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC27\uDCB0-\uDCD3]|\uD803[\uDC80-\uDCB2]|\uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCBF]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC19\uDC34-\uDC4D\uDC68-\uDC81\uDC9C\uDC9E\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB5\uDCD0-\uDCE9\uDD04\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD38\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD6C-\uDD85\uDDA0-\uDDB9\uDDD4-\uDDED\uDE08-\uDE21\uDE3C-\uDE55\uDE70-\uDE89\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEE2-\uDEFA\uDF1C-\uDF34\uDF56-\uDF6E\uDF90-\uDFA8\uDFCA]|\uD83A[\uDD00-\uDD21])([a-z\u00C0-\u017F])+$
```

This range above supports ALL uppercase characters in the unicode class set.

Then for your Nickname you can use:

- `^([\w\s\u00C0-\u017F]{1,13})$`

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
  1st Capturing Group ([\w\u00C0-\u017F]{1,13})
    Match a single character present in the list below [\w\u00C0-\u017F]{1,13}
    {1,13} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 13 times, as many times as possible, 
giving back as needed (greedy)
    \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
    \u00C0-\u017F a single character in the range between À (index 192) and ſ (index 383) (case sensitive)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: I need a little adjustment. The numbers are still allowed in firstname, I need to disable them. Spaces are not allowed in nickname, I need to enable them

Comment: @TheCzechTayen I updated it. The First name is much harder when we're only targeting uppercase unicode characters. You have to explicitly define the range, which totally sucks (I can't believe you still have to do this in JS in 2019). I've added the space for the nickname as well.

Comment: Nickname works perfect but firstname Parsing error: Invalid regular expression

Comment: Even a small adjustment. The numbers are still allowed, I need to disable them. I need only the first letter to be big and the other to be small

Comment: There are no numbers allowed. The regex pattern uses `A-Z` and then matches only `the specific unicode characters`

Comment: Weird because it allows me to write numbers and capital letters anywhere. Only the first letter should be large. In firstname

Comment: Ok last thing. Only first letter in firstname must be capital (big) a no numbers allowed (i can use them now). I playing with it here but i cant make it works

Comment: Okay, after about 6 hours of searching and testing, I fixed it. It was enough in the firstname regex to replace '/w' with 'a-z' and it already works as I needed. Thanks for the help!